# Windows Storage space disappeared?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

On my computer, I have 5 drives that I set up as a Storage Space in 'Two-way mirror'.

The other day, I had the brilliant idea to test out unplugging one of the drives to see what would happen.

Turns out, the Storage Space completely vanished from the available drives, and even from the partition manager!

I was completely panicked, I called Microsoft support but the guy didn't understand what I meant by Storage Space and  proceeded to hang up. Anyway, when I rebooted the computer for the second time after re plugging the drive it magically showed again.

Now I'm wondering, if a drive fails, do I lose my files? I thought ''two way storage'' meant there's redundancy? When I tested having a drive failure, I did loose the RAID and all my files. I'm wondering if that is normal behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: "RAID is not backup" "Backup should not be considered working until it is tested in a thorough disaster simulation" .  I've never used Storage Space, but don't assume that your data is safe.  For instance, your whole setup could be destroyed by lightning, flood, or theft of the PC.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior in a virtual machine. Removing one disk of a two-disk storage space does not make the space itself fail. Files were still accessible.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought '' two-way storage'' meant there is redundancy?

That is indeed what it means.  Storage Spaces works like a software RAID.  If a hardware failure happens to a single disk, your data is protected, since two copies of every file, exist on each drive.

However, if the entire RAID/Storage Space fails for any reason, your data is not protected.  However, that is true with a single drive, so it really isn't a reason NOT to use Storage Spaces.

[image]

[Fault tolerance and storage efficiency in Storage Spaces Direct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-fault-tolerance)

> Now I'm wondering, if a drive fails, do I lose my files?

Due to your configuration, you have a single drive redundancy, allowing for a single drive to fail.

> Each copy is written to different physical hardware (different drives in different servers) that are assumed to fail independently.

What the above quote is saying, is their example has drives in two entirely different systems, allowing a single system to be offline and the data will not be lost.  In your case both drives are in the same system, allowing a single drive to fail, and your data will not be lost.

> I'm wondering if that is normal behavior.

It is not normal behavior.

Comment: I tried to simulate a drive failure by unplugging the drive : was the following behavior (raid not showing anywhere) normal?

Comment: I have answered your question as it was originally written.  If there is going to be a moving goal post, of additional questions, I will just delete my answer.  The mode you are using, per the documentation, indicates you have a single drive fault tolerance

Comment: @Alde - I have answered all your questions contained in your question.  Storage Spaces configured in 2-way mirror mode is supposed to allow a single disk to fail.  That is absolutely all I will say on that matter.

Comment: I asked : Now I'm wondering, if a drive fails, do I lose my files. You said no. When I tested having a drive fail, I did loose my files.

Comment: You also said you rebooted and the drive was restored. Your original revision made no mention of permanent data loss. I have addressed your concern about the data loss, despite the fact, you made no mention of it originally. I now consider all your questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. IMO that's how Level 1 Microsoft support works.
2. If you have data only on Storage Spaces you should make an urgent backup elsewhere (in a cloud for cheap $).
3. If you lose a drive you lose all the data.

Comment: "If you lose a drive you lose all the data.", so what's the purpose of two way mirroring?